# Paypal Payments Standard not returning payment variables on iPad

Tags: ipad, paypal

I have just finished developing a website using **Paypal Payments Standard**, and all is working just fine in most computers, but paypal does not return any payment variables on iPad (and maybe other devices).

I created my own cart, and use the *Buy Now* functionality to pay for the entire order.
The *Buy Now* form sets the RETURN variable to the cart page, and the RM variable is set to 2, which should post the variables back to the cart page.

When the payment is complete, the cart page checks for posted payment variables and logs them into the database.

As said, this works perfectly on most computers.
On iPad, though, the user returns to the cart page, but no payment variables are posted. This is just the same when changing the RM variable to 1, which should send the variables as GET parameters.

You can see the code and working website at: http://unameit.ch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly an answer to your problem, but would solve the issue and would be better for you anyway.

Using your return URL is not a good way to get data into your database because even with Auto-Return enabled there is no guarantee the user would make it back to your return URL.  In such cases, that code would never run and the data would never make it into your database.

Instead, what you should use is [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).  IPN will be triggered regardless of whether or not the user makes it back to your site.  It's very similar to PDT except that instead of POSTing data back to the return URL it POSTs it to a separate listener script apart from your checkout pages.  It happens in real-time so the result would be the same as what you're trying to do now, but it would always work regardless of whether or not the user made it back to your site, and you wouldn't have to worry about issues like you're running into here with the iPad transactions.

I highly recommend you do it this way or you'll find that you're missing order data in your database even if you end up getting this particular problem resolved.

Comment: Ok, so I did what you suggested, it works ok now (payment confirmation is delivered using the IPN interface).
The problem is that the IPN message is received in a short delay, and a test user who returns to the website too soon will reach it back before the IPN executes and his shopping cart is still intact.
What should I do next ?

Comment: Are you testing it on the sandbox or are you running live tests?  IPN, as the name suggests, is typically instant.  The sandbox can be a little bit delayed at times, although it's usually pretty instant, too.  What you might want to do, though, is have your return URL notify the user that they should receive an email within a shot period of time with further instructions.  Have your IPN send them an email after it's done it's DB updating to notify them that everything is ready.  Again, this email will typically come right away so they won't have to wait long.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with the manual callback and have been speaking to PayPal tech support. They have agreed that there is a bug with this working on a mobile/tablet devices. Basically, if you go to the mobile PayPal site to make the payment, you won't get any data POSTed back to your return URL:

They have told us to use the ExpressCheckoutAPI instead:

> "Yes the ExpressCheckout works without any issues on all platforms.
>   As a mater of fact I found that the mobileWPS checkout is Wraped around the 
>   ExpressCheckout and this is the reason why your data is chopped off.
>   Some of the data is lost in translation from WPS to EC."

Sorry that this isn't a answer but at least we know that PayPal know it's a bug.

Comment: I disagree! Maybe not the answer OP wanted but if it explains why the bug ocurrs and a work-around it can stay as an answer